# How to change the Window size of an Attached Console?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console, cmd

I attach a console to my winforms using the AllocConsole function of the WinAPI:

```
Declare Function AllocConsole Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Boolean
```

I want to change the size of that window, but seems I cant, I've tried this:

```
Console.writeline("mode con cols=150 lines=60")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the .NET Console function `Console.SetWindowSize()`.  Keep in mind, this function throws an exception if the size you give is too large (based on font size and screen resolution) so be sure to check that before calling the function.

```
Console.SetWindowSize(
    Math.Min(150, Console.LargestWindowWidth),
    Math.Min(60, Console.LargestWindowHeight));
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, I will read all the Console Class methods :P

Comment: You can actually do quite a bit with the Console Class, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Curious, what can a console do that a form, shown as a dialog with a textbox, can't do?

Comment: A console is just a place to run your program text only. It's completely different then loading a form. The console itself isn't part of your application, you are just able to tell it to do a few things because your program is running inside of it.  A form/textbox is a lot more versitile, but it requres you to load the libraries to support the forms and you are not able to just run it "from the console" (well, often you can, but it pops up the form outside the console and isn't just text based)